# Repeated Tasks using Timer Interval vs Task Delay

Tags: c#

I'm implementing a scheduled job like methods and have narrowed down to approaches. One that implements a Timer Interval and the other based on Task Delay.

I've also considered using Azure Timer triggered webjobs but they do not work in a multi-instance mode. Effectively in a multi-instance application only one trigger is fired in one of the instances and the others are locked, hence increasing the instance count of my application does not increase the number of events fired.

**Method A (Timer Interval)**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var aTimer = new Timer();
        aTimer.Interval = 5000;
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEventA;
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

        var bTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        bTimer.Interval = 2000;
        bTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEventB;
        bTimer.AutoReset = true;
        bTimer.Enabled = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program at any time... ");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private static void OnTimedEventA(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event A was raised at {0}", DateTime.Now);
        });
    }
    private static void OnTimedEventB(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event B was raised at {0}", DateTime.Now);
        });
    }
}
```

**Method B (Task Delay)**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        EventAAsync();
        EventBAsync();

        Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program at any time... ");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private static async Task EventAAsync()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event A was raised at {0}", DateTime.Now);
            });
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        }
    }
    private static async Task EventBAsync()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event B was raised at {0}", DateTime.Now);
            });
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        }
    }
}
```

Both Method A and Method B, functionally do the same. 
They both call fire events A and B at regular intervals of 5s and 2s and forget. Now I'm trying to understand the pros and cons of both approaches. In the end, the events themselves run on separate threads. Theoretically and in practice which of the two should be adopted for handling many such event triggers to be scaled across multiple instances.

Any other methods are also welcome.

Comment: `Task.Delay` uses the same `Timer` internally, so pick whatever you like more.

Comment: @Evk except that using Delay, is like one shot timer, versus timer that runs periodically. One shot timer has problem and cause clock drift over time. So 2 and 5 second intervals will not be in sync after long run.

Comment: With method B, in general, I would advise you to also: (1) `await Task.WhenAll(workTask, delayTask)` instead of awaiting _just_ the delay, to avoid reentrancy, and (2) add a cancellation token and use `while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Method A** is used when you have to trigger some task at regular intervals. **Method B** is used when you have to give regular intervals between the triggering of some task.

There is a difference if the event handler (task performed after the trigger) takes a longer time to process.

**Method A :** 
No matter how much time the task in the event handler takes, the event handler keeps getting triggered at the set time interval (code has to be reentrant).

**Method B :**
Task completes then we sleep. So if the task takes different times to complete, the next trigger is also at different times

Comment: Thank you. But in Method B, I have run the actual event related code in a fire and forget fashion using a Task.Run, so does this make both do the same interval based calls?

Comment: @ManikantaReddyD Task.Run or Task.Delay just queue the work item to be run on a thread in the thread pool. Think of a situation where you have run out of threads in the thread pool (could be your event code takes a very long time to finish). Your work items start queuing up.

Comment: Hurray for highlighting reentrancy, a significant property of the timer approach.

Comment: I agree with OP that method B is actually _not_ affected by the work's running time (i.e. does not drift). They implemented it correctly for a periodic interval.

Answer (score 3):

Use timer instead, while both use the same clock as noted by @Evk but first approach runs timer permanently.

Using Task.Delay will be just as accurate but there is a short gap between finished Delay and starting new Delay. After long period they can become desynchronized. So distance between 5 and 2 second intervals will not be same as time where you started timing.

Using Timer that runs permanently doesn't have this problem.

Comment: that might be an intended behavior though