# What does it mean that an object handle has so many TimerQueueTimer references

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an app in which I suspect a memory leak. Not only in the heap, but it seems to me the whole working set is growing for each request that is made to my app. I am trying to debug it according to [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/debug-memory-leak) but I am having a hard time interpreting what I see. I am using the `dotnet-dump` tool to analyze a dump.

All in all I have 618 `DocumentClient` instances if I interpret it correctly. Of course that will add up to a lot of data in strings, byte arrays etc.

```
Statistics:
MT                    Count    TotalSize Class Name
00007f853c355110      618       187872  Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.DocumentClient
```

Here is a snippet of a single reference taken from the method table of the document client. See the pastebin for full reference. It continues for 1200+ lines with mostly `TimerQueueTimer` references.

```
  00007F85AF2F10D8 (strong handle)
-> 00007F84C80FBAD8 System.Object[]
-> 00007F84C80FBB00 System.Threading.ThreadLocal`1+LinkedSlotVolatile[[System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1+WorkStealingQueue[[System.IDisposable, System.Private.CoreLib]], System.Collections.Concurrent]][]
-> 00007F84C80FBB40 System.Threading.ThreadLocal`1+LinkedSlot[[System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1+WorkStealingQueue[[System.IDisposable, System.Private.CoreLib]], System.Collections.Concurrent]]
-> 00007F84C80FBB70 System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1+WorkStealingQueue[[System.IDisposable, System.Private.CoreLib]]
-> 00007F84C80FBBB0 System.IDisposable[]
-> 00007F84C80FBA90 System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticListener+DiagnosticSubscription
-> 00007F84C80FAF30 Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.DiagnosticListeners.HostingDiagnosticListener
-> 00007F84C80EB450 Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration
-> 00007F84C80D5688 Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.ApplicationId.ApplicationInsightsApplicationIdProvider
-> 00007F84C80D5A60 Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.ApplicationId.ProfileServiceWrapper
-> 00007F84C80D5A88 System.Net.Http.HttpClient
-> 00007F84C80D5AD0 System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler
-> 00007F84C80D5B00 System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler
-> 00007F84D80D1018 System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler
-> 00007F84D80D1000 System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionHandler
-> 00007F84D80D0D38 System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPoolManager
-> 00007F84D80D0F70 System.Threading.Timer
-> 00007F84D80D0FE8 System.Threading.TimerHolder
-> 00007F84D80D0F88 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
-> 00007F84C80533A0 System.Threading.TimerQueue
-> 00007F84D910F3C0 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
-> 00007F84D910EE58 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
-> 00007F84D910A680 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer
```

https://pastebin.com/V8CNQjR7

Do I have an Application Insights or Cosmos memory leak? Why are there so many `TimerQueueTimer` references?

Comment: `Do I have an Application Insights memory leak` you mean Cosmos memleak?

Comment: I think you'd have more success asking this question on the appropriate GitHub.

Comment: Thanks. Will try that eventually :)

Comment: In the context of network connections timers are generally being used for handling timeouts. In most use cases you only have a handful of outstanding timers, though. Try running with a thread pool with a very small number of workers. Does this reduce the number of outstanding timers? I'm wondering if the timers get restarted without canceling/destroying the old timer. Have you analyzed the communication with [https://www.wireshark.org/](Wireshark) or a similar tool to see if there are communication problems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`await Task.Delay` create new `TimerQueueTimer` on every call.

Lots of TimerQueueTimer is sign of someone is using `await Task.Delay()` in a loop, instead of using simple `new Timer()`.

`-> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Routing.GlobalEndpointManager+<StartRefreshLocationTimer>d__25
-> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Routing.GlobalEndpointManager`
 
Looks like GlobalEndpointManager of Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos [uses await Task.Delay every time exception is thrown](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/e151f4dbbc512e7eca60ea6b4c4e144e0ebfaf85/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Routing/GlobalEndpointManager.cs#L291) in StartRefreshLocationTimer method of GlobalEndpointManager.cs class

You can try few things here:

1) Check which [exception is thrown](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/e151f4dbbc512e7eca60ea6b4c4e144e0ebfaf85/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Routing/GlobalEndpointManager.cs#L282) and how to avoid it.

My guess this should help log exception:
`DefaultTrace.TraceSource.Listeners.Add(new System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener())`
(check [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracesource?view=netcore-3.1))

2) make sure [ShouldRefreshEndpoints](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/5ef49f43307abdf8106ddda9d7f866bf49abebb2/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Routing/LocationCache.cs#L239) returns false, if it's ok for your app :)

Comment: Great answer. Thanks.

Comment: @EvgeniyKucheruk could you go into more detail regarding _Lots of TimerQueueTimer is sign of someone is using await Task.Delay() in a loop, instead of using simple new Timer()_? Does it mean using `await Task.Delay()` in a loop, will cause a memory leak? According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46763776/repeated-tasks-using-timer-interval-vs-task-delay) both ways should be fine for doing a repeated task. 
I'm asking as I am seeing up to 3500+ `TimerQueueTimer` when doing a `gcroot` for a specific object in a memory dump with WinDbg.